# " Incomplete Implementation " warning when creating a new project in Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, xcode

When am creating a new project in Xcode 4.5 i get the warning **" Incomplete Implementation "** . I didn't wrote a single line of code also, but getting this warning in default **"ViewController.m "** file near,

`@implementation ViewController`

Am not getting understand without writing a single line of code i get warning. Is my Xcode Crashed. Kindly suggest to solve this.

**Edited**

Also When i create a new ViewController file inside that project it is not showing any warning. Only default **" ViewController.m "** shows warning.

Comment: What’s the full text of the warning? It should tell you what’s missing. Also, what template did you use?

Comment: it is giving error because you might not have implemented any function or object in ViewController.m file that you have defined in ViewController.h file.Just check that you have implementd all functions and objects that are defined in ViewController.h file

Comment: i want to clarify you people one thing i didn't entered a single text. That's the surprise. Its just giving a plain warning "Incomplete Implementation" near the @implementation View Controller line.

Comment: Could you please tell us what template did you use to see if we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: i had selected Single View Application template

Comment: can anyone suggest a solution?